# Getting null pointer error from Volley while using PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-volley, preferencefragment

im trying to make an app where users can log in and save their userdata to an mysql-db.
Im using PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment to handle this. Usually this works fine until i change the users...

- so "user A" changes a Value in the PreferenceFragment. For Example his city. (i.e. "mainroad 1")
- Data is stored in SharedPrefs and sent to Web.
  -PreferenceScreen gets updated with the new data.
  -Everything is fine.
- UserA changes the next value, i.e. his e-mail (userA@user.com)

Now the error occurs when User A logs out and User B logs in. (shared prefs are cleared with the clear(). and commit() when logging out..)

- User B gets his own data from Web
- Data is correctly displayed in preferencescreen
- User B wants to change his e-mail address too.
- now the old EditTextPreference value from UserA (userA@user.com) is visible when i click the EditTextPreference item (dont know if this leads already to an error)
- UserB deletes it and types in his new e-mail (userB@user.com).

Application stops with

```js
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()'
on a null object reference
at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java: 43)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java: 78)
at com.jamp.jamp.UserProfileSettingsFragment.onSharedPreferenceChanged(UserProfileSettingsFragment.java: 171)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.notifyListeners(SharedPreferencesImpl.java: 479)
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.apply(SharedPreferencesImpl.java: 387)
at android.preference.Preference.tryCommit(Preference.java: 1415)
at android.preference.Preference.persistString(Preference.java: 1448)
at android.preference.EditTextPreference.setText(EditTextPreference.java: 94)
at android.preference.EditTextPreference.onDialogClosed(EditTextPreference.java: 148)
at android.preference.DialogPreference.onDismiss(DialogPreference.java: 395)
at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java: 1337)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 756)
```

Now this is the code of the fragment

```js
package com.jamp.jamp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Erikken on 05.09.2017.
 */

public class UserProfileSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
  SessionManager session;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  String prefs_realname;
  String prefs_email;
  String prefs_streetname;
  String prefs_postcode;
  String prefs_city;
  String prefs_state;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("JampSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.usersettings);

    session = new SessionManager(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());


    HashMap < String, String > user = session.getUserDetails();
    final String sessionUsername = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);

    // ResponseListener um Request Nutzerdaten auszulesen.
    Response.Listener < String > UserDataResponseListener = new Response.Listener < String > () {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
          JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
          boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

          // Wenn Datenabfrage erfolgreich, JSONResponse auswerten. // If successful, import data from mysql database
          if (success) {
            String responseRealName = jsonResponse.getString("realname");
            if (responseRealName.equals("")) {
              responseRealName = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingRealName);
            }
            String responseEmail = jsonResponse.getString("email");
            if (responseEmail.equals("")) {
              responseEmail = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingEmail);
            }
            String responseStreetName = jsonResponse.getString("streetname");
            if (responseStreetName.equals("")) {
              responseStreetName = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingStreetName);
            }
            String responsePostcode = jsonResponse.getString("postcode");
            if (responsePostcode.equals("")) {
              responsePostcode = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingPostcode);
            }
            String responseCity = jsonResponse.getString("city");
            if (responseCity.equals("")) {
              responseCity = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingCity);
            }
            String responseState = jsonResponse.getString("state");
            if (responseState.equals("")) {
              responseState = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingState);
            }
            int responseAge = jsonResponse.getInt("age");
            int responseIsPremium = jsonResponse.getInt("isPremium"); // BOOLEAN

            // Add data to shared prefs
            editor.putString("realname", responseRealName);
            editor.putString("email", responseEmail);
            editor.putString("streetname", responseStreetName);
            editor.putString("postcode", responsePostcode);
            editor.putString("city", responseCity);
            editor.putString("state", responseState);
            editor.commit();

            prefs_realname = prefs.getString("realname", "");
            prefs_email = prefs.getString("email", "");
            prefs_streetname = prefs.getString("streetname", "");
            prefs_postcode = prefs.getString("postcode", "");
            prefs_city = prefs.getString("city", "");
            prefs_state = prefs.getString("state", "");

            Preference prefUserData = (Preference) findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata");
            prefUserData.setTitle(sessionUsername);
            prefUserData.setSummary(prefs_realname + "\n" +
              prefs_email + "\n" +
              prefs_streetname + "\n" +
              prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city + "\n" +
              prefs_state);

            findPreference("settings_username").setTitle(sessionUsername);
            findPreference("settings_realname").setSummary(prefs_realname);
            findPreference("settings_email").setSummary(prefs_email);
            findPreference("settings_streetname").setSummary(prefs_streetname);
            findPreference("settings_postcode").setSummary(prefs_postcode);
            findPreference("settings_city").setSummary(prefs_city);
            findPreference("settings_state").setSummary(prefs_state);


          } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("Konnte Nutzerdaten nicht abrufen.")
              .setNegativeButton("Nochmal", null)
              .create()
              .show();
          }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }


    };
    // Request an userdatarequest.php senden / Send request to userdatarequest.php
    UserDataRequest userDataRequest = new UserDataRequest(sessionUsername, UserDataResponseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
    queue.add(userDataRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    HashMap < String, String > user = session.getUserDetails();
    final String sessionUsername = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    final String sessionPassword = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);

    Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    Response.Listener < String > UpdateUserDataResponseListener = new Response.Listener < String > () {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
          JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
          boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

          if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Change Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("Konnte Nutzerdaten nicht abrufen.")
              .setNegativeButton("Nochmal", null)
              .create()
              .show();
          }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }


    };

    if (key.equals("settings_email")) { 
      // An mySQLDB senden         
      UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername, sessionPassword, "email", sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
      queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);

      // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries 

      prefs_email = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
      findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_email);
      findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname + "\n" +
        prefs_email + "\n" +
        prefs_streetname + "\n" +
        prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city + "\n" +
        prefs_state);

    }

// LOTS OF SIMILAR BUTTONS FOLLOWING HERE...


  }
}
```

So the error uccurs only one time after relogging the user.
When it crashed once everythin seems reset, the app restarts and he can change any of his data as often as he wants.

am i using the mContext variable wrong?
are there some ramaining values i didnt clear that can lead to a crash?

any tips?  =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i got it. Found some other threads with a similar problem.

my `Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();` is called in the OnPreferenceChange method. But this seems to early because the onCreate Method in the Fragment has not been called yet and there is just no activity where my context should point, so this returns null. I moved the *mContext* variable to the onCreate method, deleted it from onPreferenceChange (made some other adjustments aswell..) and now onPreferenceChange seems to wait for the onCreate method and it works perfectly.

```js
package com.jamp.jamp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Erikken on 05.09.2017.
 */

public class UserProfileSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    SessionManager session;
    Context mContext;

    String prefs_realname;
    String prefs_email;
    String prefs_streetname;
    String prefs_postcode;
    String prefs_city;
    String prefs_state;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.usersettings);

        session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        session.CheckLogin();

        HashMap<String,String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        final String sessionUsername = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
        final String sessionPassword = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);

        // ResponseListener um Request Nutzerdaten auszulesen.
        Response.Listener<String> UserDataResponseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    // Wenn Datenabfrage erfolgreich, JSONResponse auswerten. // If successful, import data from mysql database
                    if (success) {
                        String responseRealName   = jsonResponse.getString("realname");     if (responseRealName.equals(""))   {responseRealName = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingRealName);}
                        String responseEmail      = jsonResponse.getString("email");        if (responseEmail.equals(""))      {responseEmail= getResources().getString(R.string.MissingEmail);}
                        String responseStreetName = jsonResponse.getString("streetname");   if (responseStreetName.equals("")) {responseStreetName = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingStreetName);}
                        String responsePostcode   = jsonResponse.getString("postcode");     if (responsePostcode.equals(""))   {responsePostcode = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingPostcode);}
                        String responseCity       = jsonResponse.getString("city");         if (responseCity.equals(""))       {responseCity = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingCity);}
                        String responseState      = jsonResponse.getString("state");        if (responseState.equals(""))      {responseState = getResources().getString(R.string.MissingState);}
                        int    responseAge        = jsonResponse.getInt   ("age");
                        int    responseIsPremium  = jsonResponse.getInt   ("isPremium"); // BOOLEAN

                        // Add data to shared prefs
                        editor.putString("realname",responseRealName);
                        editor.putString("email",responseEmail);
                        editor.putString("streetname",responseStreetName);
                        editor.putString("postcode",responsePostcode);
                        editor.putString("city",responseCity);
                        editor.putString("state",responseState);
                        editor.commit();

                        prefs_realname = prefs.getString("realname","0");
                        prefs_email = prefs.getString("email","0");
                        prefs_streetname = prefs.getString("streetname","0");
                        prefs_postcode = prefs.getString("postcode","0");
                        prefs_city = prefs.getString("city","0");
                        prefs_state = prefs.getString("state","0");

                        Preference prefUserData = (Preference) findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata");
                        prefUserData.setTitle(sessionUsername);
                        prefUserData.setSummary(prefs_realname+"\n"
                                                +prefs_email+"\n"
                                                +prefs_streetname+"\n"
                                                +prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city +"\n"
                                                +prefs_state);

                        findPreference("settings_username").setTitle(sessionUsername);
                        findPreference("settings_realname").setSummary(prefs_realname);
                        findPreference("settings_email").setSummary(prefs_email);
                        findPreference("settings_streetname").setSummary(prefs_streetname);
                        findPreference("settings_postcode").setSummary(prefs_postcode);
                        findPreference("settings_city").setSummary(prefs_city);
                        findPreference("settings_state").setSummary(prefs_state);


                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setMessage("Konnte Nutzerdaten nicht abrufen.")
                                .setNegativeButton("Nochmal",null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        };
        // Request an userdatarequest.php senden / Send request to userdatarequest.php
        UserDataRequest userDataRequest = new UserDataRequest(sessionUsername, UserDataResponseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(userDataRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        session = new SessionManager(mContext);
        HashMap<String,String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        final String sessionUsername = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
        final String sessionPassword = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);

        Response.Listener<String> UpdateUserDataResponseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if (success){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Change Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setMessage("Konnte Nutzerdaten nicht abrufen.")
                                .setNegativeButton("Nochmal",null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        };

        if (key.equals("settings_email")){ // Adressenprüfung mussnoch implementiert werden.
            // An mySQLDB senden
                                                                                                  //CELLNAME                           // CELLVALUE
                     UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername, sessionPassword, "email", sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
                     RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
                     queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);
                     // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries instantly
                     prefs_email = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
                     findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_email);
                     findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname + "\n"
                             + prefs_email + "\n"
                             + prefs_streetname + "\n"
                             + prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city + "\n"
                             + prefs_state);

        }

        if (key.equals("settings_streetname")){
            UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername,sessionPassword,"streetname",sharedPreferences.getString(key,""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);
            // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries instantly
            prefs_streetname = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"");
            findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_streetname);
            findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname+"\n"
                    +prefs_email+"\n"
                    +prefs_streetname+"\n"
                    +prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city +"\n"
                    +prefs_state);
        }

        if (key.equals("settings_realname")){
            UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername,sessionPassword,"realname",sharedPreferences.getString(key,""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);
            // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries instantly
            prefs_realname = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"");
            findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_realname);
            findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname+"\n"
                    +prefs_email+"\n"
                    +prefs_streetname+"\n"
                    +prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city +"\n"
                    +prefs_state);
        }

        if (key.equals("settings_postcode")){
            UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername,sessionPassword,"postcode",sharedPreferences.getString(key,""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);
            // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries instantly
            prefs_postcode = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"");
            findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_postcode);
            findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname+"\n"
                    +prefs_email+"\n"
                    +prefs_streetname+"\n"
                    +prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city +"\n"
                    +prefs_state);
        }

        if (key.equals("settings_city")) {
            UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername,sessionPassword,"city",sharedPreferences.getString(key,""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);
            // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries instantly
            prefs_city = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"");
            findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_city);
            findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname+"\n"
                    +prefs_email+"\n"
                    +prefs_streetname+"\n"
                    +prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city +"\n"
                    +prefs_state);
        }
        if (key.equals("settings_state")) {
            UpdateUserDataRequest updateUserDataRequest = new UpdateUserDataRequest(sessionUsername,sessionPassword,"state",sharedPreferences.getString(key,""), UpdateUserDataResponseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            queue.add(updateUserDataRequest);
            // Summary sofort erneuern. // Refresh Summaries instantly
            prefs_state = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"");
            findPreference(key).setSummary(prefs_state);
            findPreference("preferencescreen_userdata").setSummary(prefs_realname+"\n"
                    +prefs_email+"\n"
                    +prefs_streetname+"\n"
                    +prefs_postcode + " " + prefs_city +"\n"
                    +prefs_state);
        }
    }
}
```